# 2015 Nissan Altima

Tags: noise, nissan, altima

[image: 2015 nissan altima]
Can anyone help me to identify this intermittent metal sound ...almost as if someone was sticking a card in a metal fan or spinning spoke. i searched youtube & found a guy with exact same sound. It happens when driving intermittently.   I have a video of exactly what happens ...the sound anyway.. its on youtube. I will provide the link. block out the wind. its that other sound.
 1st link Nissan Altima 2.5s making weird metal noise" on YouTube
https://youtu.be/jirs67-F_Yo

the 2nd link is a pic with the sounds. please help if u can. 
https://youtu.be/eiGfK4yuqLQ

thank you in advance for your help. I have no one to go to for help so will try to learn from youtube if it can be diagnosed.

Comment: Can you check all your fluids (oil, coolant, transmission fluid), and confirm those are all to normal levels?

Comment: Cullub 
I can do that tomorrow. But all should be good but I will make sure. You think that could be making that sound? I never heard it before. Were you able to get a good listen? its embarrassing. Thank you btw.

Comment: I did get a chance to listen to that video -- strange!  The only thing I can think though is something related to the engine or transmission, and fluids is the quickest and easiest thing to check.

Comment: I will definitely check fluids tomorrow. & that first video has the best capture of the sound. It's weird.

Comment: fluids are full. I'm starting to think it's a heat shield. I found more videos with the exact same sound & that was all of there problems.

Comment: Going to try and jack it up & go under myself. I may be a lady but I can read and follow directions quite well. Anything you can do...I can do better. 

Comment: Good luck!  I don't know why it would be the heat shield - maybe it came loose and it's rubbing against something.  But if you can find where the noise is coming from, that's the next step.

Answer (score 1):

ok, so a clamp came loose & that's what is was. it was cracked and that's what caused the rattle. Thank you for your help Cullub.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest a possible loosening  of a heat shield or exhaust.

Comment: that is exactly what it was. easy peasy. 